# Adding new item to list of dictionaries based on existing items in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to add a new item to my dictionaries, based on the same list of dictionaries. The list of dictionaries looks something like this:

```
dict = [
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX426','GENE': 'ABC', 'ID':'001'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX426','GENE': 'BRCAq', 'ID':'002'}, 
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX426','GENE': 'RAD51C', 'ID':'003'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX406','GENE': 'ABC', 'ID':'001'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX406','GENE': 'MH1', 'ID':'002'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX406','GENE': 'MSH6', 'ID':'003'}, 
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX06','CAROTYPE': 'chr9:1-141,213,431', 'ID':'001'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX06','CAROTYPE': '9p24.3 - q34.3', 'ID':'002'}
]
```

In this dict I would like to add new item 'LIST_OF_GENES'. Values from this item should be a list of all genes with the same TESTCODE. Collect all genes from 'TESTCODE' with same value (in this example; NX426 or NX406 both have three dicts with 3 genes).
So the dict would look like this:

```
dict = [
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX426','GENE': 'ABC', 'ID':'001','LIST_OF_GENES':'ABC','BRCA2','RAD51C'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX426','GENE': 'BRCA2', 'ID':'002','LIST_OF_GENES':'ABC','BRCA2','RAD51C'}, 
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX426','GENE': 'RAD51C', 'ID':'003','LIST_OF_GENES':'ABC','BRCA2','RAD51C'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX406','GENE': 'ABC', 'ID':'001','LIST_OF_GENES':'ABC','MH1','MSH6'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX406','GENE': 'MH1', 'ID':'002','LIST_OF_GENES':'ABC','MH1','MSH6'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX406','GENE': 'MSH6', 'ID':'003','LIST_OF_GENES':'ABC','MH1','MSH6'}, 
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX06','CAROTYPE': 'chr9:1-141,213,431', 'ID':'001'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX06','CAROTYPE': '9p24.3 - q34.3', 'ID':'002'}
]
```

When 'GENE' is not there do not add new item 'LIST_OF_GENES'.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Give me the code for this problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.  You've defined the problem clearly, but we generally work to fix non-working code.

Comment: You might want to learn some basic PANDAS capabilities, as this seems to be a good place to apply `groupby` and a simply collecting function on each group.  You could also iterate through your dict, making a new dict with an entry for each test code, building the desired lists in one pass.  With this second method, you could "shorten" the loop to a not-so-readable nested comprehension.

Comment: don't use `dict` as variable name, it is builtin function, also the variable is referring to list not dict so a variable name is not apt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a long time to understand your question. Anyways try this:

```
dict = [
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX426', 'GENE': 'ABC', 'ID': '001'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX426', 'GENE': 'BRCAq', 'ID': '002'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX426', 'GENE': 'RAD51C', 'ID': '003'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX406', 'GENE': 'ABC', 'ID': '001'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX406', 'GENE': 'MH1', 'ID': '002'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX406', 'GENE': 'MSH6', 'ID': '003'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX06', 'CAROTYPE': 'chr9:1-141,213,431', 'ID': '001'},
    {'TESTCODE': 'NX06', 'CAROTYPE': '9p24.3 - q34.3', 'ID': '002'}]

# Test code name followed by set of genes, I don't want repetition.
list_of_genes = {}

for i in dict:
    test_code = i['TESTCODE']
    if test_code not in list_of_genes:
        list_of_genes[test_code] = set()
    list_of_genes[test_code].add(i.get('GENE', None))

for i in dict:
    if 'GENE' in i:
        test_code = i['TESTCODE']
        i['LIST_OF_GENES'] = list(list_of_genes[test_code])

print(*dict, sep='\n')
```

Hope this helps. If u r wondering, i is an object of the dictionary so changes made to it will reflect in the dictionaries.
Output:

```
{'TESTCODE': 'NX426', 'GENE': 'ABC', 'ID': '001', 'LIST_OF_GENES': ['ABC', 'BRCAq', 'RAD51C']}
{'TESTCODE': 'NX426', 'GENE': 'BRCAq', 'ID': '002', 'LIST_OF_GENES': ['ABC', 'BRCAq', 'RAD51C']}
{'TESTCODE': 'NX426', 'GENE': 'RAD51C', 'ID': '003', 'LIST_OF_GENES': ['ABC', 'BRCAq', 'RAD51C']}
{'TESTCODE': 'NX406', 'GENE': 'ABC', 'ID': '001', 'LIST_OF_GENES': ['ABC', 'MH1', 'MSH6']}
{'TESTCODE': 'NX406', 'GENE': 'MH1', 'ID': '002', 'LIST_OF_GENES': ['ABC', 'MH1', 'MSH6']}
{'TESTCODE': 'NX406', 'GENE': 'MSH6', 'ID': '003', 'LIST_OF_GENES': ['ABC', 'MH1', 'MSH6']}
{'TESTCODE': 'NX06', 'CAROTYPE': 'chr9:1-141,213,431', 'ID': '001'}
{'TESTCODE': 'NX06', 'CAROTYPE': '9p24.3 - q34.3', 'ID': '002'}
```

Comment: Can u upvote my answer? Actually I'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Check `itertools.groupby`

```py
from itertools import groupby

l = [{'TESTCODE': 'NX426','GENE': 'ABC', 'ID':'001'},{'TESTCODE': 'NX426','GENE': 'BRCAq', 'ID':'002'}, {'TESTCODE': 'NX426','GENE': 'RAD51C', 'ID':'003'},{'TESTCODE': 'NX406','GENE': 'ABC', 'ID':'001'},{'TESTCODE': 'NX406','GENE': 'MH1', 'ID':'002'},{'TESTCODE': 'NX406','GENE': 'MSH6', 'ID':'003'}, {'TESTCODE': 'NX06','CAROTYPE': 'chr9:1-141,213,431', 'ID':'001'},{'TESTCODE': 'NX06','CAROTYPE': '9p24.3 - q34.3', 'ID':'002'}]
l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x['TESTCODE'])

list_of_genes = {}

for group_name, group in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x['TESTCODE']):
    list_of_genes[group_name] = [i.get('GENE') for i in group]
    
for i in l:
    if all(list_of_genes[i['TESTCODE']]):
        i['LIST_OF_GENES'] = list_of_genes[i['TESTCODE']]
        
print(l)
```

```
[{'TESTCODE': 'NX06', 'CAROTYPE': 'chr9:1-141,213,431', 'ID': '001'},
 {'TESTCODE': 'NX06', 'CAROTYPE': '9p24.3 - q34.3', 'ID': '002'},
 {'TESTCODE': 'NX406',
  'GENE': 'ABC',
  'ID': '001',
  'LIST_OF_GENES': ['ABC', 'MH1', 'MSH6']},
 {'TESTCODE': 'NX406',
  'GENE': 'MH1',
  'ID': '002',
  'LIST_OF_GENES': ['ABC', 'MH1', 'MSH6']},
 {'TESTCODE': 'NX406',
  'GENE': 'MSH6',
  'ID': '003',
  'LIST_OF_GENES': ['ABC', 'MH1', 'MSH6']},
 {'TESTCODE': 'NX426',
  'GENE': 'ABC',
  'ID': '001',
  'LIST_OF_GENES': ['ABC', 'BRCAq', 'RAD51C']},
 {'TESTCODE': 'NX426',
  'GENE': 'BRCAq',
  'ID': '002',
  'LIST_OF_GENES': ['ABC', 'BRCAq', 'RAD51C']},
 {'TESTCODE': 'NX426',
  'GENE': 'RAD51C',
  'ID': '003',
  'LIST_OF_GENES': ['ABC', 'BRCAq', 'RAD51C']}]
```